# About $\frac{a}{b} \mod p_i $

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$p_1,p_2,...,p_n $ is a collection of distinct primes larger than $5$.

Fractions represent modular division.

I want to consider and understand the equation below ; existance , uniqueness etc. And of course how to solve it.

Find nonzero integers ( also nonzero mod p_i for p_i in the collection )
A and B such that

$ \frac{A}{B} \mod p_1 = \frac{A}{B} \mod p_2 = ... =  \frac{A}{B} \mod p_n $.

It is similar to the Chinese remainder.

In fact a variation is $ C =  \frac{A}{B} \mod p_1 = \frac{A}{B} \mod p_2 = ... =  \frac{A}{B} \mod p_n $.

But I do not want the restriction of the integer $C$.

Comment: Would $\frac{A}{B} = a + n\prod p_i$, some $n$, work? What would the restricitons be on $a$?

Comment: Notice this is the C i was talking about. A/B does not need to be An integer. @ Lionel

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. If your $A\over B$ means the remainder of $A$ divided by $B$, then how can it not be an integer, and how is $C$ a restriction?

Comment: Does it actually mean find $B^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ so that when such $AB^{-1}$ is divided by $p$ the remainder is the same for all $p$?

Comment: @cr001 : C is a restriction because if C_1 mod p_1 = A/B mod p_1 and C_2 = A/B mod p_2 then C_1 = C_2 is not necessarily true.